# How to say "lose a friendship/drift apart"?

Tags: words

I want to say that "as A becomes closer friends with C, B gets jealous and A and B drift apart". 
What I have so far is　A-さんは C-さんと仲良くすればするほど、B-さんがうらやましくなって、A-さんと_____てしまう。

Comment: BTW Bさんがうらやましい may in most cases mean someone (perhaps A in this sentence) being jealous of B. So, to indicate B's jealousy explicitly, you had better use a verb, うらやむ or [嫉妬]{しっと}する. I think Bさんが嫉妬して fits best here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「距離{きょり}を置{お}く」

would fit this context.

If the separation is more passive, rather than intentional/active, then

「離{はな}れ離{ばな}れになる」

These are expressions for drifting apart. "Losing/ending a friendship" has much different expressions.

「縁{えん}を切{き}る」
「関係{かんけい}を損{そこ}なう・失{うし}う」 
「～はもうおしまい」

Comment: To fill in your blank, 「距離を置くようになってしまった。」